# Explanation of Diagram of Matlab Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, data-fitting

My neural network looks like this
[image]
but I'm a bit confused by this diagram.

Clearly we have 10 input values and 2 output values.

There are also 10 hidden neurons. So I assume each of the 10 inputs are connected to each of the 10 hidden neurons?

Also what do the Ws and Bs mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to find a description of this diagram in Matlab's documentation, but it is a simplification of the diagram shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/multilayer-neural-network-architecture.html). You have one hidden layer with neurons which are each connected to all the inputs. Note that the number of neurons won't always be the same as the number of inputs, which are both 10 here. W=weights, b=biases. There is a nice intro [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bias-in-artificial-neural-network).